# FB.login, prevent launching new window, navigate in current window

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this in a mobile app and it would actually be a better user experience if the user navigated away from the app in the same window and then were redirected back.

We have the login page redirection back to our app working, but what is the best way to prevent a opening a new window when they click login?

This is the method provided by the facebook lib in yummy coffeescript -

```
FF.login = (a, b) ->
  if FB._oauth
    throw new Error("OAuth2 specification states that 'perms' " + "should now be called 'scope'.  Please update.")  if b and b.perms
    FB.ui FB.copy(
      method: "permissions.oauth"
      display: "popup"
    , b or {}), a
  else
    FB.ui FB.copy(
      method: "permissions.request"
      display: "popup"
    , b or {}), a
```

is there an alternative to `display: "popup"` that will trigger navigation in window?

or a param we can pass in?

**EDIT:**

I found this in the FB.ui method:

`"display" must be one of "popup", '+'"dialog", "iframe", "touch", "async", "hidden", or "none"'`

Do I need to edit the login method directly or can I pass in these display options as params?

**EDIT2:** I guess I could do this?

```
window.location='https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&cancel_url=YOUR_ESCAPED_CANCEL_URL&fbconnect=1&next=THE_ESCAPED_URL_TO_RETURN_TO_AFTER_LOGIN&return_session=1&session_version=3&v=1.0&req_perms=ESCAPED_LIST_OF_REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS'
```

Any way to make this work better with the existing FB.login method?

Thanks!

Comment: I think when user click on login we can make the page display none and display the login components in the same page using some jquery stuff like fadein or fadeout.It looks pretty simple and rich AFAIK. :-)

Comment: Cool, can you elaborate on this technique? Sound like what we are looking for.

Comment: I'm actually find with a wondow.location switch too if it works with the facebook, JS SDK on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

FaceBook has updated the Keyword "Perms" to "Scope" while migrating to OAuth2.0, please change the  keyword "Perms" to "Scope"

*Old Code :     // }, { perms: 'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access' });

New Code:        }, { scope: 'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access' });*

Just comment or remove old Perms to Scope.